# STUN connection not completing

Tags: c, browser, webrtc, stun

I am writing an RTP relay and am stumbling upon a problem.

Based on the libnice threaded example I have written the part of the software
that uses STUN to connect to a javascript running in chrome.

Basically this is what happens on my software side:

waiting for state READY or FAILED signal...
SIGNAL: state changed 1 1 connected[3]
State is now connected
SIGNAL: state changed 1 1 ready[4]
State is now ready

so cleary libnice is firing my callback stating that the connection is
firmly established

wireshark is showing binding indication packet

but and that is the stumper

Here is the log from chrome in webrtc internals:

```
Time    Event
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    setRemoteDescription
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    signalingstatechange
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    receiverAdded
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    setRemoteDescriptionOnSuccess
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    createAnswer
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    createAnswerOnSuccess
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    setLocalDescription
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    iceconnectionstatechange
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    signalingstatechange
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    setLocalDescriptionOnSuccess
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    icegatheringstatechange
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    icecandidate (host)
29/10/2018, 19:59:11    icegatheringstatechange
```

the iceconnectionstatechange with the firm connection is never fired.
which means that chrome never detected the established connection after
the last trickle whereas my program does.

The last iceconnectionstatechange fired in chrome is "checking"

how do i go about debugging that ???

Any help truly appreciated

Thanks

/Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You might need [stun consent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7675) which uses binding requests / response instead of binding indications. Also try declaring your peer as a lite implementation by adding a=ice-lite to the SDP.

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt answer, I do not know how and if libnice does implement stun consent. I have tried to add a=ice-lite to the sdp but that didn’t help.

Comment: Addendum: libnice does not implement RFC 7675, and I am talking to Janus.js so basically it should work and it does not.